# PHP imagejpeg does not work

Tags: php

Using this logic to resize and print an image:

```
$image_path="path/to/image.extension";  
$image_path=imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);  

$width=imagesx($image_path);  
$height=imagesy($image_path);  
$new_image=imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);  
imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image_path,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$width,$height);  
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  
imagejpeg($new_image,100);
imagedestroy($new_image);
```

But I am getting image missing icon as output. What is the mistake I do? I have tried printing the variables `$width` and `$height` and it prints the dimension of source image. So the path is correct.

What could be the error?

Comment: Save the output from your script into a file (use `wget` to also probe headers). Look at it in a hexeditor. If there is textual garbage in your JPEG file, then your PHP script also outputted garbage before; rendering the file format invalid.

Comment: I checked using this imagejpeg($new_image, $saveimagepath, 100); The image is saving properly and getting open in Browser, Paint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was in the line `imagejpeg($new_image,100);`

It must be `imagejpeg($new_image);` Quality must not be included in that, if not intended to save.